# Which Android device has BIOMETRIC_STRONG (Class 3) face authentication?

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I have implemented biometric authentication in my application with biometric level **BIOMETRIC_STRONG (Class 3)**. The fingerprint authentication is working as expected but I couldn't able to test the face authentication on any of my devices (Samsung Galaxy S10, Oppo A3S, etc.). I think the face authentication in those devices is not falling under Class 3.

Are there any Android devices with **BIOMETRIC_STRONG (Class 3)** face authentication? It would be helpful if someone can provide a list.

Comment: I have the same question, so far the only device I know with class 3 faceID is Pixel 4.

Comment: @TorkelVelure you should post that as an answer, it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit: Pixel 8 now has Class 3 face authentication too.

---

Pixel 4 is currently the only device with face authentication that qualifies as BIOMETRIC_STRONG (Class 3).

Face authentication was not added to pixel 5, and looks like there are no plans to add it back with Pixel 6 either.

This is true as of 5th October 2021, but there might be more devices that support in the future.

Source: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:biometric/biometric/src/main/res/values/devices.xml

Comment: Torkel Velure, do you have the source of this statement, so I can reference it an a research? Thank you.

Comment: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:biometric/biometric/src/main/res/values/devices.xml

Comment: if I want to use face authentication on another device, how could I do that?

Comment: To use face authentication on other devices you lower the security requirement to class 1 or 2, depending on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Pixel 8 series are now classified as Class 3.

https://www.biometricupdate.com/202310/pixel-8-boasts-improved-biometrics-with-face-unlock